# When there are minor version differences in Cassandra, node operation and different version upgrade issues

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Excuse me,

1. Can 3.11.10 nodes be added to the 3.11.4 cluster?
2. If I want to upgrade from 3.11.4 to 3.11.10, do I need to run upgradesstables?
   Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's not recommended to mix different versions of Cassandra inside the cluster, except the time when you're doing upgrades.  This comes from the possibility of having some differences in the streaming protocol that is used for bootrapping/removing the nodes, and doing repairs.  But it could be ok for versions inside the same major version (3.11), but it makes sense to change the changelog for any changes that may affect streaming.

For upgrade from 3.11.4 to 3.11.10 you don't need to run upgradesstables - this step is always **optional**, as SSTables will be written in the new format when the compaction happens.   Usual recommendation to execute it explicitly mostly for cases where you can benefit from better performance using the new file format, or having bug fixes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this solved a big problem for me.